# R Function Return multiple data.frames without using print()

Tags: r, function

Is there anyway to return multiple data.frames without printing the data.frames in an R function.  This is probably R functions 101 but not sure why when there is only 1 data.frame you don't have to print it.  You just call the final `cran` with dplyr query.

```
require(readr)
require(dplyr)

check_for_logfile <- function(date) {
  year <- substr(date, 1, 4)
  src <- sprintf("http://cran-logs.rstudio.com/%s/%s.csv.gz",
                 year, date)
  dest <- file.path(basename(src))
  if(!file.exists(dest)) {
    val <- download.file(src, dest, quiet = TRUE)
    if(val)
      stop("unable to download file ", src)
  }
  dest
}

num_download <- function(pkgname, date) {
  for (i in 1:length(date)){
    dest = c()
    dest[i] <- check_for_logfile(date)

    cran <- read_csv(dest[i], col_types = "ccicccccci", progress = FALSE)

    print(cran %>% filter(package %in% pkgname) %>% 
      group_by(package) %>%
      summarize(n = n()))
  }
}   

num_download(c("filehash", "weathermetrics"), date = c("2016-07-20","2016-07-21"))
```

Comment: Instead of `for`, use `lapply` or `purrr::map` and return a list of data frames, or use `do.call(rbind, ...)` or `purrr::map_df` to iterate and coerce the result to a single combined data frame.

Comment: thanks this looks very unpretty if unpretty was a word `num_download <- function(pkgname, date) {
  
  cran <- lapply(lapply(date, check_for_logfile),read.csv) 
  map(cran, ~filter(.x, package %in% c("filehash", "weathermetrics")) %>% group_by(package) %>% summarize(n = n())) %>% purrr::map_df(~ data.frame(.x))
  }`  any way to clean it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code, refactored a little:

```r
library(tidyverse)

num_download <- function(pkgname, date){
    # vectorized
    srcs <- glue::glue("http://cran-logs.rstudio.com/{substr(date, 1, 4)}/{date}.csv.gz")
    dests <- basename(srcs)

    # download.file is not vectorized, so iterate in parallel; return nothing
    walk2(srcs, dests,
          function(src, dest){
              if (!file.exists(dest)){
                  val <- download.file(src, dest, quiet = TRUE)
                  if (val) stop("unable to download file ", src)
              }
          })

    dests %>% 
        # read files into list and rbind into data frame
        map_dfr(read_csv, col_types = "ccicccccci", progress = FALSE) %>% 
        filter(package %in% pkgname) %>% 
        count(package)
}
```

And it works:

```r
num_download(c("filehash", "weathermetrics"), date = c("2016-07-20","2016-07-21"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   package            n
#>   <chr>          <int>
#> 1 filehash         378
#> 2 weathermetrics    13

tidyverse_downloads <- num_download(tidyverse_packages(), Sys.Date() - 8:2)

arrange(tidyverse_downloads, desc(n))
#> # A tibble: 25 x 2
#>    package      n
#>    <chr>    <int>
#>  1 tibble   69849
#>  2 rlang    59816
#>  3 cli      53371
#>  4 crayon   52918
#>  5 ggplot2  51213
#>  6 stringr  45042
#>  7 dplyr    43151
#>  8 magrittr 40455
#>  9 jsonlite 36851
#> 10 httr     30539
#> # ... with 15 more rows
```

Hey, there was a new tibble release last week that added a crayon dependency.

Comment: i like that code thanks.  nice to see it aggregated together. it would also be nice to figure out how to 1) keep it separated by the download date, in the order you entered the vector of download dates and 2) in the order of the vector you enter for packages. so for `num_download1(pkgname = c("weathermetrics", "filehash", "ggplot2"), date = c("2016-07-20","2016-07-21","2015-01-01"))` you get the first date then weathermetrics, filehash, ggplot2, same order for the second date and the then the same order for 2015-01-01 but i can't get `arrange_(.dots=pkgname)` or `arrange(!!! pkgname)` to work.

Comment: For 1, you can add a `.id = 'date'` parameter to `map_df` to add a new column from the element names, which you can then group by. For 2, you'd have to turn `package` into a factor with `pkgname` for levels so `arrange(package)` does anything beyond alphabetize. More likely, this function should do less: just download the data and combine it into a data frame, which you can then summarize how you like.